# Including phpunit code coverage in phpdoc output

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, phpdoc

For the past while I've been using phpdoc, phpunit (with xdebug for code coverage generation) and pdepend to produce documentation and code metrics. I can't help but think that things look a bit disjointed. Ideally I'd like to integrate the code coverage reports, test results and metrics together in one place — with the phpdoc output. I'm not using any CI system.

Is there anything that can help me achieve what I want to do or do I basically need to start hacking away at phpdoc and/or smarty templates?

Comment: any reason you are not using a CI server? If you are on Linux its pretty easy to get up and running with http://jenkins-php.org. That would save you the hassle of extending phpdoc.

Comment: I have looked at a few different CI servers but to be honest I don't like the output generated by any of them. I tend to be a roll-your-own kind of guy but if I could find something more customisable I'd use it in an instant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a tool for combining phpdoc and the phpunit code coverage.

For the other tools you can check out "phpcb" - [The PHP Code Browser](https://github.com/mayflowergmbh/PHP_CodeBrowser).

It will combine the result from "PHP Code Sniffer", "PHP Mess Detector" and PHPUnits "CRAP" index by giving you a source code browser where you can look at the code an all the errors in one place.

Screenshots from a sample project:

[image: phpcb-overview-page]

[image: phpcb-classview-page]